# Neural networks and large data sets

Tags: java, neural-network, deep-learning, large-files, backpropagation

I have a basic framework for a neural network to recognize numeric digits, but I'm having some problems with training it. My back-propogation works for small data sets, but when I have more than 50 data points, the return value starts converging to 0. And when I have data sets in the thousands, I get NaN's for costs and returns.

Basic structure: 3 layers: 784 : 15 : 1

784 is the number of pixels per data set, 15 neurons in my hidden layer, and one output neuron which returns a value from 0 to 1 (when you multiply by 10 you get a digit).

```
public class NetworkManager {
    int inputSize;
    int hiddenSize;
    int outputSize;
    public Matrix W1;
    public Matrix W2;

    public NetworkManager(int input, int hidden, int output) {
        inputSize = input;
        hiddenSize = hidden;
        outputSize = output;
        W1 = new Matrix(inputSize, hiddenSize);
        W2 = new Matrix(hiddenSize, output);
    }

    Matrix z2, z3;
    Matrix a2;
    public Matrix forward(Matrix X) {
        z2 = X.dot(W1);
        a2 = sigmoid(z2);

        z3 = a2.dot(W2);
        Matrix yHat = sigmoid(z3);

        return yHat;
    }

    public double costFunction(Matrix X, Matrix y) {
        Matrix yHat = forward(X);

        Matrix cost = yHat.sub(y);
        cost = cost.mult(cost);

        double returnValue = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < cost.m.length) {
            returnValue += cost.m[i][0];
            i++;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    Matrix yHat;
    public Matrix[] costFunctionPrime(Matrix X, Matrix y) {

        yHat = forward(X);

        Matrix delta3 = (yHat.sub(y)).mult(sigmoidPrime(z3));
        Matrix dJdW2 = a2.t().dot(delta3);

        Matrix delta2 = (delta3.dot(W2.t())).mult(sigmoidPrime(z2));
        Matrix dJdW1 = X.t().dot(delta2);

        return new Matrix[]{dJdW1, dJdW2};
    }
}
```

There's the code for network framework. I pass double arrays of length 784 into the forward method.

```
    int t = 0;
    while (t < 10000) {
        dJdW = Nn.costFunctionPrime(X, y);

        Nn.W1 = Nn.W1.sub(dJdW[0].scalar(3));
        Nn.W2 = Nn.W2.sub(dJdW[1].scalar(3));

        t++;
    }
```

I call this to adjust the weights. With small sets, the cost converges to 0 pretty well, but larger sets don't (the cost associated with 100 characters converges to 13, always). And if the set is too large, the first adjustment works (and costs go down) but after the second all I can get is NaN.

Why does this implementation fail with larger data sets (specifically training) and how can I fix this? I tried a similar structure with 10 outputs instead of 1 where each would return a value near 0 or 1 acting like boolean values, but the same thing was happening.

I'm also doing this in java by the way, and I'm wondering if that has something to do with the problem. I was wondering if it was a problem with running out of space but I haven't been getting any heap space messages. Is there a problem with how I'm back-propogating or is something else happening?

EDIT: I think I know what's happening. I think my backpropogation function is getting caught in local minimums. Sometimes the training succeeds and sometimes it fails for large data sets. Because I'm starting with random weights, I get random initial costs. What I've noticed is that when the cost initially exceeds a certain amount (it depends on the number of datasets involved), the costs converge to a clean number (sometimes 27, others 17.4) and the outputs converge to 0 (which makes sense).

I was warned about relative minimums in the cost function when I began, and I'm beginning to realize why. So now the question becomes, how do I go about my gradient descent so that I'll actually find the global minimum? I'm working in Java by the way.

Comment: Recognizing digits is a classification problem and not a regression problem. You should consider using 10 outputs each corresponding to one digit and choose the recognized digit based on the output neuron with the highest output value.

Comment: Yeah, I've actually switched back to the 10 output framework

Answer (score 1):

If your backprop works on small dataset is there really good assumtion that there isn't problem. When you're suspicious about it you can try your BP on XOR problem.

Are units biased?

I once discuss with guy who doing exactly same thing. Hand digit recognition and 15 units in hidden layer. I saw a network who doing this task well. Her topology was:

Input: 784

First hidden: 500

Second hidden: 500

Third hidden: 2000

Output: 10

You have a sets of images and you nonlinear transform 784 pixels of image into the 15 numbers from <0, 1> interval and you doing this for all images of your set. You hope that you can right separate digit based on these 15 numbers. From my point of view is 15 hidden unit too little for such a task when I assumed you have dataset with thousands of example. Please try for example 500 hidden units.

And learning rate has influence on backprop and can caused problem with convergence.

Comment: I'm actually not using biases, and I think I should be. I would initialize them randomly, but how would I adjust the biases in training?

Comment: Exactly same as normal weights. But you consider bias unit output as 1, so update rule for bias is delta bias for ith neuron = error signal_ofithneuron* learning_rate.

Comment: So I put in biases, and for small data sets the network is learning quicker than before (which is good), but it's still having the problem where the outputs converge to 0 for larger data sets...

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a problem with weight initialization.

As far as i can see you never initialize the weights to any specific value.  Therefore the network diverges. You should at least use random initialization.

Comment: I do initialize with random values, I just didn't post that section of the code

Comment: Then i would adjust the learning rate. It is one of the other things that can make your network diverge. Additionally input data might be contrary and this can also impact convergence.

Comment: Would you recommend a high or low learn rate? Also, wouldn't it be best to have the learning rate be variable throughout training?

Comment: I would recommend training different learning rates. Normally you do intervalls of 10 so [0.1, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001]. After it actually trains you can still deal with stuff like changing the learning rate after the validation error stops improving. But nowadays with decay it is not needed anymore.